# How to Update a java application published on google play console to flutter app

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, google-play-console

I have published an app with a package name (com.syedirfanhussaini.tables) in Google Playstore and I want to update my app that is now made in flutter, also have made all the necessary changes in my code.

new flutter app made with the same package name (com.syedirfanhussaini.tables) as an old native app that is already published in the google play store.

Now, my main question is that can I update my new flutter App with a Native app without changing the Package name in the google play store,

will Google play console allow me to update the flutter app with the same package name over the same native app?

Comment: Was your last version APK or app bundle?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is update the build number and replace apk you have in production with the new one. If the app reflects the screenshots you have on the store, and optional credentials needed for review of the app work you are good to go. Play/App Store doesn't care about the language in which the app is built as long as it complies with the store guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You mean I can update my app.